# Program for Google Sites in Python

Tags: python, automation, browser-automation

I must get the URLs of all subpages found within one Google Site in the editor mode. I have a subpage for each Form(1 to 6 Upper) of all classes at school. However, I intend to automate any future changes using Python code. I must be able to access each page and upload photos to the subpages under each one. But, for that, I must get onto the subpage itself.
Basically, the web structure goes like this:

EVERYTHING -> CLASSES -> SUBJECTS

I have tried using Selenium for automation but that idea didn't work out since I cannot log in with Google once it enters automation mode since Selenium is active. I have tried using a program to simulate mouse motion and actually click on the subpages but it is far too complex and after several unsuccessful attempts, I gave up.

I need ideas on what I should do to access each subpage and retrieve its URL. I would appreciate if someone could help me because I am really stuck as I cannot hope to update the entire site manually on a weekly basis.

If someone could show me the code which would perform this task, I would appreciate it too much to express in words. No matter what, thanks very much!

Comment: Google doesn't provide any resources on automating those things?

Comment: I am trying to use the tutorial available here: https://acaird.github.io/computers/2013/05/22/gsites-with-python but it's very complex and I'm not sure I understand how it works and I don't think it has the functions I require. I also tried another one which I downloaded from Github but I got many errors while installing, about syntax error and such. I am now trying to learn to use the webbrowser module.